# css: apply rule on first <tr><th> if there are 2 <tr>

Tags: css

Is it possible apply a rule at the first `<th>` of first `<tr>` if there are 2 or more `<tr>` in `<thead>`?

I did:

```
table tr:first-child th:first-child
```

but if there is only 1 `<tr>` ti apply anyway.

Comment: If you have some default style, you can apply it to `tr:only-child th:first-child` to "override" in case of only child.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a combination of the [`:not()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/%3anot) and [`:only-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/%3aonly-child) selectors like so:

```
tr:first-child:not(:only-child) th:first-child {
    color:red;
}
```

Code is relatively self explanatory, it will only affect the first child if it isn't an only child.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/R9zhF/)

It has relatively bad [support](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-onlychild) though, you might need a [javascript polyfill](http://selectivizr.com/) to make up for it if you need to support IE8 or below.

Comment: i see that this do what i need. so it work only for new browser and for IE >= 8?

Comment: @Atomico No, [for IE>8 (i.e. IE>=9)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/:not#Browser_compatibility).

Comment: @Atomico I included a support reference if you want to read that. It works on IE9 for me, but not 8

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible without using css `class`. If you are creating tr's dynamically. I would recommend to do as below:

```
if(condition for rows > 2) {
    <tr><th class="applyCSS"></th><th></th></tr>
    <tr><th></th><th></th></tr>
    ......
}
else {     //only one tr
   <tr><th></th><th></th></tr>
}
```

**CSS:**

```
applyCSS { .... }
```